# require function and variable from another file = nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to offload some of the bulk from my app and came across this issue.

Here is my code:

```
// foo.js:

var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = {
  home: function () {
    return mysql.createConnection({
      host : '2.2.2.2',
      user: 'admin',
      password: 'xxxxxx',
      database : 'mlb'
    });
  }

// bar.js:

var dbConnect = require('./foo.js');

dbConnect.home.query('SELECT * from batters;', function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var string_data = JSON.stringify(res);
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(string_data);
  console.log(jsonData);
});
```

The error i receive is `undefined is not a function`... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, did you try to find out what exactly is undefined? Is it `dbConnect.home`? Is it `dbConnect.home.query`? If you're running in Firefox, it could even be `console.log`. Which is it? The error should provide you with the line of failure, at least, and some easy debug statements should tell you the rest. Also, IIRC, mysql connections need to be connected before you can query them, no?

Comment: line of failure is `dbConnect.home.query('SELECT * from batters;', function(err, res, body) {` Arrow indicating query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't home need to be like this:
`dbConnect.home().query`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to instantiate the imported function before calling its method.

Correct code for bar.js is:

```
var dbConnect = require('./test.js');

var connection = dbConnect.home();

connection.query('SELECT * from batters;', function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var string_data = JSON.stringify(res);
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(string_data);
  console.log(jsonData);
});
```